# Is it possible to replace uploaded assets?

Tags: assets

I have a site that uses several PDF forms that update from time to time. Instead of adding a new asset, I would rather replace the existing one.

I couldn't see how to do that from within the Craft admin. I suppose it's possible to do via FTP, but I'd really like it to be able to be done by the client.

Am I missing something, or is this not possible at this time?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This actually is possible if you navigate to the folder or sub folder where you are trying to add the asset and then upload a file with the exact same file name.

Craft will ask you if you want to replace the existing file or upload another version with an appended name (for example "my-file-1.txt")

Comment: Right, totally forgot about it. Since it is possible to upload from the entry form, I almost never visit the assets section in the CP. But yeah, that's currently the best way to handle updating/replacing! Thanks for your answer, Peter!

Comment: Absolutely! It's one of those "hidden" features I discovered awhile ago by the same method (ie, asking the question). I believe it was a feature request somewhere to make this more explicit for the end user.

Comment: Thanks! Ya I'd love this to be more visible in the future. Maybe in the context menu when right clicking on an asset.

Comment: There's a rumor this might be addressed in the 2.2 release.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it's currently possibly **[from the entry section]**. You'll always end up with a new file, filename and URL, if an asset already exists with the same file name. To be able to upload an updated version of that asset, you'd need to properly delete the old file first.

There was a related [feature request](https://plus.google.com/110713469361173113445/posts/i2w5vDFGmd7) on +g not long ago. Jamie Wade asked to make it possible to delete (and rename) assets through the asset field **while editing an entry**. If this get's implemented, your client should be able to update the assets with ease. You should just tell him the difference between the minus sign (to just remove the relation), and the UI for proper deletion.

.

*Edit:*

*This is only true, if you're dealing with assets from the entry section the the Control Panel. Currently the best way to replace / update assets is through the assets section in the CP ([see Peter's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1554/125)), some things probably change with Craft 2.2 though.*