# Listen to replacing files through CP's assets section

Tags: plugin-development, assets, control-panel, replace

Admin users can replace asset files without having to deal with re-uploading/re-creating a new asset using the feature/technique described in Peter's answer here: [Is it possible to replace uploaded assets?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/is-it-possible-to-replace-uploaded-assets). This has the advantage of preserving any values in the asset's custom fields.

I need to populate some of those fields dynamically though, so they correspond to the new file for the asset. So, I wrote a small plugin that listens to the [assets.onReplaceFile](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#assets-onReplaceFile) event like so:

```
craft()->on('assets.replaceFile', function(Event $event) {
  Craft::dd($event->params); // or whatever
});
```

But the code in the handler never gets executed. Is this the right event to listen to this specific user action or is there another event for it? Or am I doing something wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Where does that code live?  In your plugin's `init()` method?

Comment: Yes, in the `init()` method of the plugin's main class.

Comment: Can you describe the workflow you're using where you're expecting the event to get fired?